# Error when comparing dates in spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

Faced with such an error, how can it be solved?

```
Failure/Error: specify{ subject[:ends_at].should eq challenge.ends_at.as_json }

   expected: "2014-08-29T08:20:47.019-05:00"
        got: "2014-08-29T08:20:47.000-05:00"
```

Comment: Without more information, I don't see many people being able to help you. Is there something wrong with your test? Is your test pointing out a problem in your code? What is your code? Error messages can point to any number of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare without milliseconds or try freeze time https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop